# How can I make basic writing via Google Sheets API?

Tags: ios, swift, google-sheets-api

On my way of learning Google Sheets API with Swift I wanted to write a single range to a spreadsheet.

Looking into [Quickstart iOS Guide](https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/ios?ver=swift) and [Basic Writing examples](https://developers.google.com/sheets/samples/writing) I came with this code:

```
func constructAndSendAQuery() {
    let baseUrl = "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets"
    let spreadsheetId = "1FhbBdEvpcyHsdfgsdft65eDGHre2fLVki5ZolMmZaRs"
    let range = "Sales!A31:C31"
    let url = baseUrl + "/" + spreadsheetId + "/values/" + range
    let params = ["valueInputOption": "RAW"]
    let fullUrl = GTLUtilities.URLWithString(url, queryParameters: params)

    let body = GTLObject()
    body.JSON = ["majorDimension":"ROWS",
                 "values": ["One", "Two", "Three"]]

    service.fetchObjectByInsertingObject(body, 
                                         forURL: fullUrl,
                                         delegate: self, 
                                         didFinishSelector: #selector(ViewController.processTheResponse(_:finishedWithObject:error:)))
}
```

Don't know what I did wrong but I got the error message: "The requested URL wasn't found on this server".

Answer (score 1):

As @sam-berlin mentioned I should have used `fetchObjectByUpdatingObject` instead of `fetchObjectByInsertUpdating`.

But there was one more little mistake/typo. In constructing JSON I lost a pair of square brackets and got an error about invalid value.

The working code looks like this:

```
func constructAndSendARequest() {

    let baseUrl = "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets"
    let spreadsheetId = "1FhbBdEvpsfgzb3Akn1opmru0iresdfglbki5ZMmZaRs"
    let range = "Sales!A3:D3"
    let url = baseUrl + "/" + spreadsheetId + "/values/" + range
    let params = ["valueInputOption": "RAW"]
    let fullUrl = GTLUtilities.URLWithString(url, queryParameters: params)


    let body = GTLObject()
    body.JSON = ["range": range,
                 "majorDimension": "ROWS",
                 "values": [["One", "Two", "Three"]]]

    service.fetchObjectByUpdatingObject(body, forURL: fullUrl, delegate: self, didFinishSelector: #selector(ViewController.processTheResponse(_:finishedWithObject:error:)))   
}
```

It's also possible to use `service.fetchObjectByUpdatingObject(body, forURL: fullUrl, completionHandler: nil)` and not process the response.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [GTLService code](https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client/blob/master/Source/Objects/GTLService.m#L2127), `fetchObjectByInsertUpdating` does a `POST`, whereas this request requires a `PUT`.  It seems that `fetchObjectByUpdatingObject` should do a `PUT`, so try that instead.

Answer (score 0):

If someone needs, I answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51585042/updating-specific-row-in-ios-swift-using-google-spreadsheet-api/52413833#52413833) on the similar question.
You can use the `GTLRSheets_ValueRange()` object and `GTLRSheetsQuery_SpreadsheetsValuesUpdate.query(withObject:` to create or update any cell through Google Sheets API.

```
let service = GTLRSheetsService()
service.authorizer = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().currentUser.authentication.fetcherAuthorizer()
service.apiKey = Constants.GOOGLE_SPEADSHEET_API_KEY
let rowIndex:Int = job.rowIndex
let range = "Employee List!C\(rowIndex):C\(rowIndex)"
let valueRange = GTLRSheets_ValueRange()
valueRange.range = "Employee List!C\(rowIndex):C\(rowIndex)"
valueRange.values = [[job.jobTitle!]]
valueRange.majorDimension = "COLUMNS"

let query = GTLRSheetsQuery_SpreadsheetsValuesUpdate.query(withObject: valueRange, spreadsheetId:  Constants.SPREAD_SHEET_ID, range: range)
query.valueInputOption = "USER_ENTERED"

service.executeQuery(query) { (ticket, response, error) in
    print(response)

}
```