# Updating specific row in iOS Swift using Google SpreadSheet API

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have been working on Google SpreadSheet API in iOS swift, but theres a problem in updating a specific field in SpreadSheet row/data in iOS Swift,

Following is the code that adds one row on the top of spreadsheet, But I want on a particular index or matching a particular value,

```
  let service = GTLRSheetsService()
            service.authorizer = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().currentUser.authentication.fetcherAuthorizer()
            service.apiKey = Constants.GOOGLE_SPEADSHEET_API_KEY
            let range = "Employee List!A2:D"
             let valueRange = GTLRSheets_ValueRange.init()
             valueRange.values = [[job.jobTitle!]] //want to add job title on specific field after maching employee name

            let query = GTLRSheetsQuery_SpreadsheetsValuesUpdate.query(withObject: valueRange, spreadsheetId:  Constants.SPREAD_SHEET_ID, range: range)
    query.valueInputOption = "USER_ENTERED"

    service.executeQuery(query) { (ticket, response, error) in
        print(response)

    }
```

This Code adds job title on the top of B2 column, but I want to add this on a specific row, by checking the name and then add job against it.

PS: The data looks like this

[Want to add job title by matching the particular employee name, ref to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UURCt.png)

Can somebody help me out?

Thank you very much

Comment: I would highly suggest that you go over the [Reading & Writing Cell Values](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values) as it teaches you on how to read/write on a specific cell. There are also [sample Sheet API calls](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/) that you can infer from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define an exact range for a cell you are going to update. It might look like this:

```
let service = GTLRSheetsService()
service.authorizer = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().currentUser.authentication.fetcherAuthorizer()
service.apiKey = Constants.GOOGLE_SPEADSHEET_API_KEY
let rowIndex:Int = job.rowIndex
let range = "Employee List!C\(rowIndex):C\(rowIndex)"
let valueRange = GTLRSheets_ValueRange()
valueRange.range = "Employee List!C\(rowIndex):C\(rowIndex)"
valueRange.values = [[job.jobTitle!]]
valueRange.majorDimension = "COLUMNS"

let query = GTLRSheetsQuery_SpreadsheetsValuesUpdate.query(withObject: valueRange, spreadsheetId:  Constants.SPREAD_SHEET_ID, range: range)
query.valueInputOption = "USER_ENTERED"

service.executeQuery(query) { (ticket, response, error) in
    print(response)

}
```

And don't forget to define a right `scope` in `GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes`