# GoogleSignIn ios append to google sheets

Tags: ios, google-signin, google-sheets-api

I'm currently working on an iOS app that needs to write to a google sheet owned by the user who is signed in.

To sign in the user I'm using the `GoogleSignIn` pod and for appending to the google sheet I'm using the `GoogleAPIClientForREST/Sheets` pod.

I can get the user to sign in ok, but for the life of me I can't seem to write to a sheet due to authentication errors. Every example I've found on SO ( like [Updating specific row in iOS Swift using Google SpreadSheet API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51585042/updating-specific-row-in-ios-swift-using-google-spreadsheet-api))  and the like states to use an `fetcherAuthorizer()` method of the current user and assign it to the `service.authorizer`, however this won't even compile with the following error `value of type 'GIDAuthentication?' has no member 'fetcherAuthorizer'`

So for my podfile I have:

```
pod 'GoogleSignIn'
pod 'GoogleAPIClientForREST/Sheets'
```

My `AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` has the following:

```
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = "clientIdHere"

    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.scopes.append(kGTLRAuthScopeSheetsSpreadsheets)
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.scopes.append(kGTLRAuthScopeSheetsDrive)
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.delegate = self
```

And when I try to write to the sheet I use:

```
    let service = GTLRSheetsService()
     // following line errors with authorizer not being a property of the service 
     //variable and fetchAuthorizer() not being a method on authentication
service.authorizer = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().currentUser.authentication.fetcherAuthorizer()
        let spreadsheetId = "id"
        let range = "Sheet1"
        let valueRange = GTLRSheets_ValueRange.init();
        valueRange.values = [
            ["Hello", "World"]
        ]
        let query = GTLRSheetsQuery_SpreadsheetsValuesAppend
            .query(withObject: valueRange, spreadsheetId:spreadsheetId, range:range)
        query.valueInputOption = "USER_ENTERED"

        service.executeQuery(query) { (ticket, any, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            }
            print(any)
            print(ticket)
        }
```

I've tried using a standard URLSession with an `authorization` header such as

```
let data = ["range":"Sheet1!A1:D1", "majorDimension":"ROWS", "values": ["123","123","123","123"]] as [String : Any]
    urlRequest.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "content-type")
    urlRequest.addValue(GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()!.currentUser.authentication.accessToken, forHTTPHeaderField: "authorization")
    urlRequest.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: data, options: .sortedKeys)
    let session = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, response, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
        } else {
            print(String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8))
        }
    }.resume()
```

but this also fails telling me I need to pass an access token along. Can anyone advise how this should work? I just seem to be going round in circles with the docs and all the other examples I can find seem to use methods/properties that don't seem to exist!

These are the current pod versions I'm using

```
Using GTMOAuth2 (1.1.6)
Using GTMSessionFetcher (1.2.0)
Using GoogleAPIClientForREST (1.3.6)
Using GoogleSignIn (4.2.0)
Using GoogleToolboxForMac (2.1.4)
```

And I only ever call the method to write to the sheet when I know I have a user.

Thanks

Comment: `fetchAuthorizer` vs `fetcherAuthorizer` vs `...Authorizor`? When you inspect the headers of the request you're sending, is the access token sent as the `Authorization` header with value `Bearer + <token>`?

Comment: One of those fetchAuthorizor or fetcherAuthorizor is a typo in the question but it wasn’t in the actual code

Comment: And the `zer` vs `zor`? And the request headers?

Comment: Sorry I fixed those typos to the correct names now. It looks like the currentUser is nil so the authorization header isn't getting set when I use a standard URLSessionDataTask, which is weird as they can't actually get to that page unless they're signed in and that check has already happened

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For anyone else facing similar issues, I managed to get this working with the GoogleAPIClient.

The issue is to do with Swift *silently* dropping imports for forward declarations.

So you need a bridging header as follows

```
#import <GTMSessionFetcher/GTMSessionFetcher.h>
#import <GTMSessionFetcher/GTMSessionFetcherService.h>
```

and this needs to be imported before the APIClient framework in whatever class you use this in.

e.g

```
import GTMSessionFetcher
import GoogleAPIClientForREST
import GoogleSignIn
```

you should then be able to access the `authorizer` property and `fetcherAuthorizer()` method!

Comment: Your answer just saved my @$$ @TommyBs . For anyone interested: Swift 5 (running in Xcode 11.2) no longer needs the bridging header, just adding `import GTMSessionFetcher` to your file is good enough

Comment: You save my time. I have been search the solution for many days. Even for Google SignIn latest sdk v6, if you are using Swift, it still has this error. `let authorizer = authentication.fetcherAuthorizer()` cannot find `fetcherAuthorizer` in Objective-C library.