# Integrate Google drive into my app: Value of type 'GIDAuthentication' has no member 'fetcherAuthorizer'

Tags: ios, swift, google-drive-api

I try to integrate google drive into my app to list mp3, m4a music files. Now I have made `Google sign` working, means I could signIn and signOut google account.

But when I follow google's api doc to this step [Make an API call with fresh tokens](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/api-access), I got above error on line `let authorizer = authentication.fetcherAuthorizer()`. This function `fetcherAuthorizer` is not found.

I think maybe this doc is not up to date with latest google sdk. So I did a few search on Google...then it appears there is really rare stuff about this topic. What I found is all used this same code `authentication.fetcherAuthorizer()`.

Thus, guys. Is there any update about this code?

```
user.authentication.do { authentication, error in
    guard error == nil else { return }
    guard let authentication = authentication else { return }

    // Get the access token to attach it to a REST or gRPC request.
    let accessToken = authentication.accessToken

    // Or, get an object that conforms to GTMFetcherAuthorizationProtocol for
    // use with GTMAppAuth and the Google APIs client library.
    let authorizer = authentication.fetcherAuthorizer()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Today, I find the answer in this thread [googlesignin-ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52762379/googlesignin-ios-append-to-google-sheets)

The reason is Swift cannot find the `fetcherAuthorizer` from Objective-C library, we must manually import it `import GTMSessionFetcher`.