# How to write to a Google Sheet from Android app programmatically

Tags: java, android, google-sheets

HELP! I have looked so long and read the documentation at https://developers.google.com/sheets/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update on how to write to a Google Sheet but I still do not understand. 
 I do not have any code examples because I do not know how to if it is any help my question is like the android version of the IOS [Write Google sheet cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37515634/write-google-sheet-cell) question.  One thing I do know is that it seems that I need to use spreadsheets.values.update as it says in the linked documentation but I need help on implementing it.

Has anybody ever used this?

Well, does anyone know how to format a ValueRange, or know how to format the command spreadsheets.values.update?

Comment: Related SO Question: [Writing to Google Drive spreadsheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27753329/writing-to-google-drive-spreadsheet)

Comment: It is similar, but that is for version 3, and the answer is only about authentication which I already know how to do.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?